# "Те, благодаря которым" или "те, благодаря кому"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, местоимения

Как правильно сказать: "Помним тех, благодаря **которым** мы можем..." или "Помним тех, благодаря **кому** мы можем....."?

Answer (score 1):

**Помним тех, благодаря кому мы можем.....**

Нашел в сети ответ, который совпадает с моим пониманием.

["кто" или "который"?](https://forum.unilang.org/viewtopic.php?t=32473)

> Разница употребления с одушевленными:
>
> Тот, кто не опаздает, получит премию миллион евро. 
>   Работник, который не опоздает, получит премию.
>
> Я видела кого-то, кто вчера был с тобой.
>   Я видела парня, который вчера был с тобой.
>
> Если встретишь того, кому должен - верни деньги!
>   Если встретишь человека, которому должен - верни деньги!
>
> То есть **если слово, к которому относится местоимение, выражено тоже местоимением, то надо ставить КТО**.

Comment: Вряд ли такое правило универсально: в контексте может быть заложен выбор из одушевлённых сущностей, на одну из которых далее ссылается первое местоимение из рассматриваемой конструкции. _Я знаю, ты должен одному из тех ростовщиков. Если наведается **тот** [из упомянутых], **которому** должен, лучше сразу отдай деньги._

Comment: @Alex_ander, Согласен, но трудно это сформулировать. Может так: "тот, который" говорят, когда подразумевают одного из  некоей известной из контекста группы?